# Tikz: Strange color change.

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, shadows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using opacity in TikZ causes strange rendering in Acrobat.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/using-opacity-in-tikz-causes-strange-rendering-in-acrobat)

This is a nice pice of TikZ for typesetting Go boards (gobans).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

%% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{wood}{rgb}{0.80,0.65,0.36}

\newcommand{\goban}[2]{
  \clip (0.3,0.3) rectangle (#1+0.5,#2+0.5);
  \fill [color=wood] (0,0) rectangle (20,20);
  \draw [step=1] (1,1) grid (19,19);
  \draw [thick] (1,1) -- (1,19) -- (19, 19) -- (19, 1) -- cycle;
  \foreach \row in {4, 10, 16} {
    \foreach \column in {4, 10, 16} {
      \fill (\row,\column) circle (0.07);
    }
  }
}

\tikzstyle{stone}=[
  ball color = #1!70!gray,
  circle,
  %drop shadow,
  minimum size = 0.95cm
]

\newcommand{\wstone}[2]{\node[black,stone=white] at (#1) {#2};}
\newcommand{\bstone}[2]{\node[white,stone=black] at (#1) {#2};}

%% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \goban {10} {7}
  \bstone {4,4} {}
  \wstone {6,3} {1}
  \bstone {3,6} {2}
  \wstone {4,2} {3}
  \bstone {3,3} {4}
  \wstone {9,3} {5}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}

%% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The "drop shadow" is commented out.
If I uncomment it a shadow appears where it should, but also a whole picture become darker.
Why such thing is happening? How can I avoid it?

Comment: No colour change in Evince on Ubuntu....

Comment: Yes. Looks like a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest check your output using another pdf viewer, if there are differences as well. It could be a reader issue.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141/why-are-some-pages-in-my-pdf-coming-out-bold (shadows most likely use transparency).