# Package pgf Warning

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm working with MikTex2.9 and I couldn't get rid of this warning message:

Package pgf Warning: Your graphic driver pgfsys-dvips.def does not support fadings. This warning is given only once on input line 31.

By trying this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{ball} = [circle,shading=ball, ball color=red!80!white,  drop shadow=black, minimum size=1cm]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [style=ball] {blah blah blah};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I got a .pdf slightly different from the .dvi file (the shadow is a little lighter) and I was wondering if this problem could be linked with the warning or if it's only a problem of the reader (as reported in: [Tikz: Strange color change.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1915/tikz-strange-color-change) ).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: @Arianna: why don't you compile to PDF directly? With pdfTeX I don't get that warning.

Comment: By compiling to PDF I don't get the warning, but the shadow is always lighter (it should be black)

Comment: @Arianna: ok, "I got a .pdf slightly different from the .dvi file" just read to me like you created the .pdf from the .dvi (dvips/ps2pdf or dvipdfmx), that's why my pdfTeX suggestion.

Comment: from .dvi (with dvips/ps2pdf);  from .tex to .pdf with LaTeX => PS => PDF(latex.exe) and with LaTeX => PDF(pdflatex.exe)

Comment: Which version of TikZ/pgf do you use? 2.0 or 2.10?

Comment: 2.10 (pgf_2.10.tds) and I installed it according to this message: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-to-install-a-current-version-of-tikz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the drop shadow is slightly transparent, which often results in unpredictable behavior when rendering via dvi/postscript.

The default settings for the shadow are `opacity=.5, fill=black!50`, i.e. medium gray and half transparent.

To turn off the transparency use something like `drop shadow={black,opacity=1}`.

[image: ball with black shadow]

Comment: Thanks Caradmir for your suggestion. Now I get what I expected.

Comment: @Arianna. As this answer seems to solve your problem, please 'accept' it by selecting the tick you should see under the voting arrows.