# Beamer reflections with pgf/tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I want some nice reflections in my slides. Something like the ones seen in Jobs Keynotes.

[image]

Suppose you have multiple elements in the tikz picture and you want to reflect the whole thing with fading.

How can I achieve this using pgf/tikz?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think that TikZ has support for copying contents. So the best idea I have is creating a command for the contents and then using that twice—the second time with appropriate transformations and fading applied. Here is a proof of concept:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfpageattr{/Group <</S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fadings}


\begin{document}
\newcommand\tikzcontents{
    \fill[red] (-1,-2) rectangle (1,0.5);
    \node (a) {first line};
    \node[below=of a] (b) {second line}; 
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzcontents
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-4.5cm,yscale=-1,transform canvas,transform shape]
        \path[scope fading=south] (-1,-4) rectangle (1,0.5);
        \tikzcontents
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: proof of concept]

Be aware that not all pdf viewers have support for fadings. For example, Evince won't display them properly. The `\pdfpageattr` line is to work around a bug in Acrobat Reader (see [“Using opacity in TikZ causes strange rendering in Acrobat”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/using-opacity-in-tikz-causes-strange-rendering-in-acrobat)).

Comment: Compare also the title page of the current TikZ manual.

Comment: The 2.x TikZ/PGF has support of copying content, e.g. in the `spy` library. However, I don't think it is much different to the technique you are using.

Comment: And works with overlays too!

Comment: An alternative solution using spy would be a great addition!

Comment: @baol: The `spy` library is for spyglass effects, i.e. some area is zoomed out. I just mentioned it as example that TikZ can copy content. I don't think it supports shadings, at least not out of the box.