# Is there a way to rotate all pages in XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex, landscape

I known there is a `landscape` command to set horizontal pages, but this is not I want. My purpose is to typeset vertical CJK with `XeLaTeX`. The general approach is using `\rotatebox{-90}` get a vertical paragraph in a box. It works for a single paragraph in one page; The disadvantage is that it can not deal with more complex situations such as multiple pages. I am wondering if there is a way to rotate the all pages?

Comment: Do you know want *all* pages, i.e. the complete document in landscape as the title says, or only several pages? For pdfLaTeX I would suggest `pdflscape` but I don't think it will work for XeLaTeX.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer I am going to rotate all the pages __with rotated text__.

Comment: Is there a way to rotate pages with unrotated text?

Comment: @Martin pdflscape works fine xelatex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[nofonts]{ctexart}
\newfontlanguage{Chinese}{CHN}
\setCJKmainfont[Script=CJK,Language=Chinese,Vertical=RotatedGlyphs]{SimSun}

% rotate the page
\usepackage{everypage}
\AddEverypageHook{\special{pdf: put @thispage <</Rotate 90>>}}

\begin{document}
帝高陽之苗裔兮，朕皇考曰伯庸。
\end{document}
```

BTW, you'd better discuss these topics at [CTeX forum](http://bbs.ctex.org) . It is strange to answer your question here for me.

Comment: Thanks for the link, now I know where we can send others with these issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the `pgfpages` package that is part of the `pgf` bundle.  Unfortunately there is a [bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1911195&group_id=142562&atid=752792) in the 2.10 release.  There is a [simple fix](http://old.nabble.com/pgfpages-and-rotation-tt26508856.html#a26508856), though, which you can patch in like this:

```
792a793,801
> % MPL 2011-04-20 08:04:45
> % patch to fix bug in rotation.  See
> % http://old.nabble.com/pgfpages-and-rotation-tt26508856.html#a26508856
> %        \expandafter\ifx\csname pgfpages@p@\the\pgf@cpn @rotation\endcsname\relax%
> %           \pgfscope%
> %        \else%
> %          \pgflowlevel{\pgftransformrotate{\csname pgfpages@p@\the\pgf@cpn @rotation\endcsname}}%
> %        \fi%
>         \pgfscope%
794d802
<           \pgfscope%
```

(the only substantial change is that a `\pgfscope` macro is moved from within an `\ifx...\fi` to before it.)

Here is a sample to see how it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{down}{}{%
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=1,%
    physical height=8.5in,
    physical width=11in
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {%
    rotation=-90,
    center=\pgfpoint{0.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{0.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}
\pgfpagesuselayout{down}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

This was all going great until I tried compiling with xelatex, and I got that the physical page size did not change.  But we are 90% there.