# Beamer/TikZ shadow printed via Adobe Reader (PostScript) cause errors

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, viewers, printing, postscript

Consider the example below compiled using `pdflatex`. Basically it is a simple test of the Frankfurt theme and the Whale color theme (just attempting to make something smaller).

We experience problems with this example when printed on our Konica Minolta C360.

When we print from Adobe Reader, on Linux (or Mac, or from Windows using a PostScript Driver), the print is ignored. Prints fine if printed on Canon, HP or Oki, also print fine if we do not use Adobe Reader!

AR also prints on the KM, if the file is made using `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`.

I'm having some discussions with KM as to what the problem is.

Here are a few interesting observations.

If I print the PDF to a PS file on Linux using AR 8, the Adobe Distiller 9 on Win7, complain and recreate a PDF that is flawed.

AR X on Win 7, freezes if I attempt to print the PDF to a file.

The main problem in the PDF is the shadow, there is no problem if I remove the shadow.

Does anyone know if there are Adobe problems in regards to some of the shadings used by TikZ? (when compiling with `pdflatex`)

I can provide some of the generated files if needed.

I use an up to date TL 11 system to create the offending PDF.

Any comments?

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@themerounded@shadow{true}
%\def\beamer@themerounded@shadow{false}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
\usecolortheme{whale}
\title{Test}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Shades and transparencies are a relatively recent PDF feature and a beast with respect to their transition to Postscript, which is usually happens when printed. Take a look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40123/3751). Even though the question and problem was something different and the solution does not immediately apply to your problem, it may explain the backgrounds that cause the troubles.

Comment: Just to rule out AR: Does it work if you print from other PDF Readers? Which one have you tested?

Comment: @Daniel: `Xpdf` works fine plus I can print this very file just fine from AR, **on all of our other PostScript capable printers**

Comment: Basically I'm trying to find ways to explain to the manefacturer that their PostScrupt interpreter has a problem

Comment: Can you please try to print the sphere I have [in this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54327/3235)? Please scale it down before you print to save ink. If it does, than it might be something related to TikZ formulation.

Comment: Interesting, the KM printer does not like it when printed from Adobe Reader. Though it does print it if I use `latex` + `dvips` and then print the PS as is.

Comment: Oops, I've seen this only now. Is there any progress for this problem?

Comment: No KM has not reacted much more than the expected *please update your driver*, basically displaying the they do not understand the problem. Is there any way of testing if the printer include the pdf14 postscript extensions?