# How to black out a figure for confidential reasons?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I have a document, that contains critical parts. Now two documents should be generated. One version that is "balcked out" and one version that is all readable.

For pure text I found some hints using the `soul` package. See http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=18190

Now I have the problem, that there are also some figures (drawn with tikz) that should be hidden. Is there a way to handle this?

Edit:
I got two very good answers how to do it. Unfortunately I use the externalization library of tikz. The criticat pictures I of course do not export to avoid problems with the file numbers. But the on compiling the other pictures (after one in a `Btikzpicture` or a `ctikzpicture`) have problems to compile as latex finds the `\tikzpicture` but it seems not to see the `\enttikzpicture` and therefor runs into trouble. Have you here also a solution. I tried using `\NewEnviron` but this did not solve the problem as I think.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newif\ifblackOut
% \blackOuttrue
\ifblackOut
\newenvironment{ctikzpicture}
    {\tikzset{external/export next=false}
    \adjustbox{precode=\phantom,bgcolor=black!10}
    \bgroup\tikzpicture}
    {\endtikzpicture\egroup}
\else
\newenvironment{ctikzpicture}
    {\tikzset{external/export next=false}
    \tikzpicture}
    {\endtikzpicture}
\fi
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
% 
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{ctikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{ctikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
% Uncomment next lines for other error
% \begin{figure}[htbp]
% \centering
% \begin{tikzpicture}
% \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
% \end{tikzpicture}
% \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The solution depends on what you call "document".  "Blacking out" for the printed version is quite simpler than "blacking out" for the PDF file in a manner where the information is reliably absent from the file.

Comment: It would be optimal if it backs out even for the pdf file. But if you have an idea for only printing, that would also be very welcome.

Comment: Does it keep the text in the PDF when you use the `phantom` option? If not, you could try something like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43069/how-to-replace-a-large-block-of-text-by-an-empty-block-of-the-same-size and just make the box black. (This is only for the text part, though, not for the figure.)

Comment: For plain text there is the [`censor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/censor), which has facilities for censoring either the output PDF or the source `.tex` file.

Comment: Would you please make a code example?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just define a `Btikzpicture` environment that can behave differently under a set conditional and use it for the pictures that you want to selectively omit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newif\ifsecret
% \secrettrue % uncomment for the hidden version

\ifsecret
%%% code for blanking TikZ pictures
\newsavebox{\Btpbox}
\newenvironment{Btikzpicture}
  {\begin{lrbox}{\Btpbox}\begin{tikzpicture}}
  {\end{tikzpicture}\end{lrbox}%
   \fboxsep=-\fboxrule\fbox{\omission\phantom{\usebox{\Btpbox}}}}

\newcommand{\omission}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\,\tiny OMITTED\strut}}
%%%
\else
%%% code for normal printing
\newenvironment{Btikzpicture}{\tikzpicture}{\endtikzpicture}
%%%
\fi    

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    every node/.style={
        circle,
        draw,
        solid,
        fill=black!50,
        inner sep=0pt,
        minimum width=4pt
    }
}
\begin{Btikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.8,->,shorten >=2pt]
    \draw (0,0) node {} -- (1,1) node {};
    \draw (1,1) node {} -- (2,1) node {};
    \draw (2,1) node {} -- (3,2) node {};
    \draw (3,2) node {} -- (4,1) node {};

    \draw  (0,2) node {} -- (1,1) node {};
    \draw (1,2) node {} -- (2,1) [dashed] node {};
    \draw (2,1) node {} -- (3,2) node {};
    \draw (3,2) node {} -- (4,1) node {};

    \draw (2,1) node {} -- (3,0) [dashed] node {};
    \draw (2,1) node {} -- (2,0) [dashed] node {};
    \draw (3,0) node {} -- (4,0) [dashed] node {};
    \draw (3,0) node {} -- (4,-1) [dashed] node {};
    \draw (1,1) node {} -- (1,0) [dashed] node {};
\end{Btikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(The picture code is taken from an answer by Jake.)

When `\secrettrue` is uncommented, only a frame of the correct size will be drawn; only the metric information will be in the final output.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `adjustbox` to replace the content with a black (or gray, to save ink) rectangle.

Note that this solution will not write the censored content into the PDF.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\iffalse
\newenvironment{ctikzpicture}{%
    \tikzpicture
}{%
    \endtikzpicture
}
\else
\newenvironment{ctikzpicture}{%
    \adjustbox{precode=\phantom,bgcolor=black!10}\bgroup
    \tikzpicture
}{%
    \endtikzpicture
    \egroup
}
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{ctikzpicture}[thick]
    \draw (0,0) -- (10,10);
    \node at (5,5) {Secret information};
\end{ctikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

With recent version of `adjustbox` (i.e. v1.1 2018/04/08) you can just write `phantom` as a key and also add some "Censored" text on top of it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}[2018/04/08]
\usepackage{tikz}

\iffalse
\newenvironment{ctikzpicture}{%
    \tikzpicture
}{%
    \endtikzpicture
}
\else
\newenvironment{ctikzpicture}{%
    \adjustbox{phantom,bgcolor=black!10,foreground={rotate=45}{\sffamily Censored!}}\bgroup
    \tikzpicture
}{%
    \endtikzpicture
    \egroup
}
\fi

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{ctikzpicture}[thick]
    \draw (0,0) -- (10,10);
    \node at (5,5) {Secret information};
\end{ctikzpicture}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `\censorbox` command from my `censor` package can block out boxed material like figures, tables, etc.  Here is an excerpt from the docs:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

As you are using externalization anyway, you could also delegate the blackening to some external program that is invoked for the image to externalize via the `external/system call` key. The amazing thing (I have learned it from Andrew Stacey in the process of answering [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40050/using-opacity-in-tikz-makes-the-entire-page-become-more-coarse-when-printed)) about this key is that you can pass an arbitrary sequence of commands as long as the final output is a PDF.

In the following, I use [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org)'s `convert` utility to replace the generated PDF by one with a [simply filled canvas](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#blank) immediately after it has been generated by `pdflatex`. By defining own styles, the confidential mode can be activated/deactivated with `\tikzset` globally or on a per-picture base.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

% setup externalization
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{
  confidential tikz/.style={
    external/system call={%
      pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"; 
      convert "\image".pdf -fill Tan -draw 'color 0,0 reset' "\image".pdf}
  },
  public tikz/.style={
    external/system call={%
      pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}
  }
}


\tikzset{confidential tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick,rounded corners=8pt] 
  (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (1,3.25) -- (2,2) -- (2,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,2) -- (0,0) -- (2,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{public tikz}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick,rounded corners=8pt] 
  (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (1,3.25) -- (2,2) -- (2,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,2) -- (0,0) -- (2,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is based on Image Magic right?

Comment: @ChristianWolf: Right. I have now explained this in detail.

Comment: @ChristianWolf: Note also, that with this solution there is no need to disable externalization for the confidential images, as the generated image file itself is overwritten by the `convert`-generated one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tikz solution, set the scale to a low value and use color to blank it out (there are possibly more solutions, such as xshift=-2000pt).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={color=white,scale=0.0001}}
\begin{document}
abcd

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (1) at (0.1,0.2);
\coordinate (2) at (0.2,0.7);
\coordinate (3) at (0.4,-0.3);

\draw let \p1 = (1),
          \p2 = (2),
          \p3 = (3),
          \n{denom} = {(\x1 - \x2)*(\x1 - \x3)*(\x2-\x3)},
          \n{A} = {(\x3*(\y2-\y1) + \x2*(\y1-\y3) + \x1*(\y3-\y2))/\n{denom}},
          \n{B} = {(\x3*\x3*(\y1-\y2) + \x2*\x2*(\y3-\y1)+\x1*\x1*(\y2-\y3))/\n{denom}},
          \n{C} = {(\x2*\x3*(\x2-\x3)*\y1 + \x3*\x1*(\x3-\x1)*\y2 + \x1*\x2*(\x1-\x2)*\y3)/\n{denom}} in
          plot[domain=\x1:\x3] (\x,{\n{A}*\x*\x+\n{B}*\x + \n{C}});
\end{tikzpicture}

abcd
\end{document}
```

As mentioned in the comments though, you need to decide if you sending the original file or not. Other strategies would include importing the figures from files, which you do not include in the final draft you sending out.