# PDF looks ugly in Okular/Acrobat Reader and fine in Evince

Tags: rendering

(I don't know whether this question is on-topic, but I will ask it anyway.)

I'using XeLaTeX and Beamer to prepare a presentation. The problem is that although the resultant pdf renders fine in Evince (Linux), the colors and the shapes look ugly in Okular (Linux) and Acrobat Reader (both Linux and Windows).

That wouldn't be a problem, If I could use my laptop in the presentation room. But this is not the case. Hence, I'm afraid that my presentation will look ugly and I will be embarrassed, even though I'm seeing it perfectly fine at the comfort of my home.

Here is the various program versions I'm running:

```
stathis:% xelatex --version
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.0
Copyright 2014 SIL International, Jonathan Kew and Khaled Hosny.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 52.1; using 52.1
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.8; using 1.2.8
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.5.3; using 2.5.3
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.2.4; using 1.2.4
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 0.9.29; using 0.9.35
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.10; using 1.6.10
Compiled with poppler version 0.26.2
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.11.1; using 2.11.1
stathis:%
```

I'm using the MgOpen Cosmetica font and regarding the images I embed in the pdf, I do se with \includegraphics{}.

Here is the good rendering:
[image: The good]

And here is what I consider the ugly one:
[image: The ugly]

Any thoughts on how to debug my problem? Am I doing something wrong at the TeX level?

---

I'm also providing two links to high resolution version of the images:

The good: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25202446/good.png

The ugly: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25202446/bad.png

Note that the tables in the images are graphics that I load with graphicx package. But I have similar problems with plain text.

Comment: Different PDF viewers render things in different ways. That, basically, is life. However, you don't say (1) what concerns you in particular or (2) anything about what you are doing at the TeX level. So it is hard to know (1) what the problem is and (2) whether it is due to something you are doing at the TeX level. A small, compilable document which reproduces the issue would be helpful. Though it is probably just PDF viewer differences which doesn't have anything to do with TeX.

Comment: Thanks @cfr for bothering. If you click on the links at the end of my question, you will probably realize what I mean by ugly. E.g., the 'i' in the word 'Patients' looks very bad. I will try to provide a MWE later today. Thanks.

Comment: Does it resolve if you zoom in? If so, it is certainly a rendering issue.

Comment: Really looks like a rendering issue. Why don't you print the page with a printer to find out?

Comment: I'm worried because I'm preparing a presentation and I don't know how it will look like in the presentation room (I won't have my laptop). Perhaps Latex/Beamer isn't good for my use case scenario ?

Comment: My LaTeX-generated pdfs look always ugly in Linux version of Acrobat Reader. When it comes to presentation, there is always a Windows machine and the pdf looks fine in Acrobat Reader. If you have to use Linux stay with evince/okular. But run through the presentation one time before you start giving the presentation. When you run through the file the second time there be will no delays when loading the next page. Delays could happen, when run through the file for the first time.

Comment: The links for the hi-res images don't work for me, each leading to an HTTP 404 Error.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? It is almost certainly a rendering issue. We don't know anything about the code you are using to produce the presentation. Note that it cannot be a bug in `poppler` simply if it affects `acroread` as well. And `evince` is also `poppler`-based. That said, my presentations look fine in Okular and, certainly, `acroread` on Windows. (I think on Linux, too.) Haven't tried Evince. But, then, I may be doing something completely different from you at the TeX level.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/using-opacity-in-tikz-causes-strange-rendering-in-acrobat/130315#130315

Comment: Might be of interest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62669/acrobat-reader-changes-my-themes-color, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16061/includegraphics-pdf-color-problem and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137151/asymptote-transparency-causes-strange-color-rendering-in-adobe-acrobat.