# Baffling interaction of Asymptote and Transparency

Tags: incompatibility, asymptote, transparency

*Context:* I'm trying to use Asymptote to draw explanatory arrows and comments atop a semitransparent `lstlisting` environment. In the course of doing so I've encountered a bizarre interaction between Asymptote and the package `transparency` that I've reduced to a minimal working example. I'm using LuaLaTeX but can reproduce in pdfLaTeX too.

For reasons not understood to me, an Asymptote `asy` environment will sometimes, though not always, almost completely disable transparency *inside* and *outside* and both fore and aft of the `\begin{asy} ... \end{asy}` block. Here's the MCVE example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\usepackage{transparent}

\begin{document}
\section{Before Asymptote}
{\transparent{0.1}Ghost X}
\section{In Asymptote}
\begin{asy}
if(false){                 //TOGGLE THIS
    label("x");
}else{
    draw((0cm,0)--(1cm,0));
}
\end{asy}
\section{After Asymptote}
{\transparent{0.1}Ghost X}
\end{document}
```

There is an `if` statement with a toggle inside, currently `false`. When it is set to `false`, I get ghostly text before and after the `asy` drawing:

[image: Ghostly X]

However, if I set the toggle to `true`, I don't:

[image: Unghostly X]

Note how both the text before and after is no longer transparent.

Variants I've tested:

- The contents of the label are irrelevant.
- Wrapping `asy` in a `figure` or `minipage` does not contain the disease.
- Nor does adding `\pdfpageattr{/Group <</S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>}` in the preamble or any other incantations as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/using-opacity-in-tikz-causes-strange-rendering-in-acrobat).
- Both TeXStudio's embedded viewer and KDE's Okular show this, so it's not a peculiarity of the PDF viewer.
- I've also just tried `texpreamble("\usepackage{transparent}");` and `label("{\transparent{0.1}x}");` and got the same results for both toggles, and $x$ was not transparent.
- When you set the toggle to `true` and do both `label("x");` and `draw((0cm,0)--(1cm,0), opacity(0.1));` in the `if-`side of the branch, you get the same result (transparency disabled fore and aft), **but the drawn line *is* transparent**.

Why do only some Asymptote figures trigger spooky-action-at-a-distance and blow up everything else like this? And how can I work around it?

Comment: Does putting a group around the `asy` block help at all?

Comment: @cfr Not at all. That was the thing I tried before `figure` and `minipage`, If wrapping with `minipage` doesn't sandbox it, it's basically impossible for `{}` to sandbox it.

Comment: Looks like this bug is fixed in the newest version anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still don't know why it's happening, but here's a workaround for the MCVE:

1. Use `asypictureB` package instead of `asymptote`. (Correspondingly, change all `asy` environments to `asypicture`, both `\begin` and `\end`, and make sure to add the mandatory argument after `\begin{asypicture}`.
2. Add the line `settings.outformat="pdf";` to the beginning of your `asypicture`s. Otherwise it will get compiled to `eps`, which can cause peculiar spacing.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\usepackage{transparent}

\begin{document}
\section{Before Asymptote}
{\transparent{0.1}Ghost X}
\section{In Asymptote}
\begin{asypicture}{name=foo}
settings.outformat = "pdf";
if(true){                 //TOGGLE THIS
    label("x");
}else{
    draw((0cm,0)--(1cm,0));
}
\end{asypicture}
\section{After Asymptote}
{\transparent{0.1}Ghost X}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

The only clue I have as to the reason is that the `asymptote` package has tighter interaction with the LaTeX code than the `asypictureB` package. This allows the `asymptote` package to automatically copy the fonts and packages used in the main document, but apparently it also allows for issues like this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just came back here to report that adding `settings.inlineimage=false;` fixes the problem _outside_ `asy`, albeight `texpreamble("\usepackage{asymptote}");` and `label("{\transparent{0.1}x}");` still do not render a ghostly x _within_ `asy`.

Comment: In general, the TeX commands to change color, transparency, etc. are not expected to function correctly inside Asymptote labels. Instead, modify the `pen` used for the label.

Comment: Although now that I do some experimentation, I'm not sure that a pen's `opacity` actually affects labels. The color certainly does.

Comment: [Apparently it's arbitrarily impossible](https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/blob/master/doc/asymptote.texi#L3089).

Comment: You, sir, are a genius, and `asypictureB` is the fruit of your prodigy. It was definitely worth it to nuke the default OpenSuSE TeX install, which dates back to 2013, and instead replace it with the legitimate TeXLive that contains your package. I don't even need to double-run `lualatex` - your implementation that involves executing a script handles it in one pass. One thing however: You should add to the answer the need for `-shell-escape`, otherwise things fail to work.

Comment: Charles, I found out that it _is_ possible to get transparent and colored labels by way of `\transparent{0.2}\color{green}` or suchlike  - but one must invoke `asy` manually with argument `-twice`, or else use `settings.twice=true;`. Not because one needs to resolve references, but because when you run `asy -vv` you're treated with this: `Package transparent Warning: Rerun to get transparencies right.`. Running `asy` twice doesn't work - it seems like it deletes whatever `transparent` collected during its first run. I will be marking your answer and package as the solution in due time. Cheers!