# Color and Transparency of a Figure in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: graphics, color, transparency, adobe, acrobat

I usually use TeXShop in Mac to make a document, and I had a problem with figures: The color and fonts are weird when I open the PDF file with Adobe Acrobat. I found a lot of questions and answers about this problem in Google and here including [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/using-opacity-in-tikz-causes-strange-rendering-in-acrobat), and basically the answer is simply adding the following line in the preamble.

```latex
\pdfpageattr{/Group <</S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>}
```

It worked, and everything is fine. But I do not know the meaning of the above line. I just want to know what it means and why we should insert it in the preamble. Thank you.

Comment: there is some longer discussion about this here https://github.com/latex3/graphics-def/issues/16

Comment: Which version of Adobe Acrobat (or is it Acrobat Reader?) do you employ? If it's no the latest version, can you update it and check if the problem persists?

Comment: @Mico I always use the latest version. Actually the problem was solved by the above command that I do not understand, so the question is the meaning of the command.