# Unintential bolding when inserting image

Tags: graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are some pages in my PDF coming out bold?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141/why-are-some-pages-in-my-pdf-coming-out-bold)

Occasionally a file I'm editing will render a page in very heavy text, making the entire page look bold, when I insert an image on that page.  This doesn't happen all the time, but I have noticed it happen in a few different files.  Why does this happen; and is there a way around it?  I'm using the graphicx package for inserting images (with pdftex) and compiling to pdf.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example (including the preamble) that shows the described behaviour? What format are the images that cause this behaviour?

Comment: Have you noticed this strange behaviour for a particular format of the offending images (are all of them in the same format)?

Comment: Is this the same issue as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141/why-are-some-pages-in-my-pdf-coming-out-bold?

Comment: It is the same error - thanks!  Fixed it by converting files to jpg.