# How do I prevent \includegraphics from rendering in bold in Acrobat?

Tags: pdf, bold

I believe I'm seeing the same problem mentioned [here](http://mokitieus.blogspot.com/2009/03/includegraphics-causes-entire-page-to.html), but just to summarize:

When I use `\includegraphics` for a PDF, any other text on that page is rendered **in bold** in Acrobat 9 *if 2D hardware acceleration is used*.

Is there any solution for preventing this (aside from turning the PDF into a raster format like JPG or PNG, and obviously aside from changing my PDF reader or turning off 2D graphics acceleration)?

---

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics{Bad.pdf}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Bad.pdf (base64):

```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```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example and the information about your operating system and TeX distribution?

Comment: @egreg: Sure, I added it.

Comment: Thanks for adding the example code. However, it should be minimal, e.g. not include anything which is not required (here I think the `subfig` code) but all things which are required: here some text, so we can see how it turns bold.

Comment: I can't recreate the issue under Linux (2D acceleration seems to be only available for the Windows version of Adobe Reader), so here some tips about thing I would try: 1) Put a `\normalfont` after `\includegraphics[..]{..}`. 2) Filter the included PDF through some PDF tool like Ghostscript, maybe it is defect or just not 100% standard compliant.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Yes, that's why I mentioned 2D graphics acceleration (in *italics!*) -- it only happens with that option (which I guess is only on Windows). And yes, it does seem to be a PDF issue -- it happens for some PDFs, but not others. Funny thing is, all of the PDFs are created the exact same way from SVG files (through Inkscape), so I'm guessing the SVGs are somehow different, but I can't tell how...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141/why-are-some-pages-in-my-pdf-coming-out-bold)?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, I got that it only happens with 2D acceleration. I just wanted to point out that and way I and quite a lot of other people can't recreate the issue. Did you tried the two points I mentioned?

Comment: @MikeRenfro: Goog catch. In this case I would recommend to try the fix mentioned in [Using opacity in TikZ causes strange rendering in Acrobat.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/using-opacity-in-tikz-causes-strange-rendering-in-acrobat)

Comment: @MikeRenfro: Maybe? Although I have version 9.4.6, so idk...

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Nope, I didn't try `\normalfont` yet. As for Ghostscript, I'd rather not install another piece of software... if that's the only solution, I'll just live with this. (Also, the `\pdfpageattr{/Group <</S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>}` thing didn't work.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16061/5763

Comment: If the PDF in question has transparency, can you remove it? If you can, does that make the problem go away?

Comment: @MikeRenfro: Yes, it does, and no, that doesn't fix it. In fact, the *other* PDFs have transparent backgrounds too, but only a couple of them cause this problem.