# Text appearing bold on some pages with images

Tags: graphics, xetex, lyx, bold

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are some pages in my PDF coming out bold?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141/why-are-some-pages-in-my-pdf-coming-out-bold)

For some reason, all the text on certain pages is appearing bold when there is a picture on the same page. I saw the other similar questions and tried converting the images firstly to PNGs with no transparency but that didn't fix it. I then tried converting them to JPEGs which didn't work either. Finally I converted them to EPS which also didn't fix the issue.

I am using Lyx and Xetex. I am viewing the file using Adobe Reader 10 on Windows 7. Below is an example of one the pages which comes out bold:

```
\begin{figure}
\noindent \centering{}\includegraphics[width=330pt]
{ReportImg/projectedmarkermodel}
\caption{Example showing the projected marker corners based around the marker with ID 0\label
{fig:Example-showing-the} }
\end{figure}

\subsubsection{Objective function}

We first needed to define the new objective function to minimise.
The objective function will...
```

The whole page comes out bold. I tried printing the page as well, it appears bold when printed.

EDIT: I don't think this is the same problem as previous questions, I have tried all the solutions given as answers before but the result is the same. I have even tried different PDF viewers and it still appears bold.

Comment: the only time I have seen this happen is with images that had an extra channel, (alpha, transparency). Are you sure you wiped out the alpha channel? If you have ImageMagick, you can use `identify -verbose filename`

Comment: I tried converting to JPG using ImageMagick to get rid of this problem even though I didn't believe any of the images had transparency. It didn't seem to make any difference though.

Comment: appears to be a problem similar to those reported in these questions: [why-are-some-pages-in-my-pdf-coming-out-bold](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141/), [using-opacity-in-tikz-causes-strange-rendering-in-acrobat](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/), [includegraphics-pdf-color-problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16061/), and [how-do-i-prevent-includegraphics-from-rendering-in-bold-in-acrobat](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38426/).

Answer (score 11):

I had such an issue when mixing pages with images with and without transparency. If you experience this in Acrobat Reader (almost all including recent versions), but not other PDF readers, the following code in the preamble might do the trick and enforce the same RGB rendering for all pages (for xelatex):

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
\makeatletter%
\special{pdf: put @thispage <</Group << /S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>> >>}%
\makeatother%
}
```

For pdflatex use:

```
\pdfpageattr {/Group << /S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>}
```

Comment: Does the `\pdfpageattr` still require the `eso-pic` package?