# Ipe transparency changes colors

Tags: pdf, ipe

I have some trouble when applying transparency to ipe objects - colours become much more grayish. We have for instance this example (ipe capture / final pdf capture):

[image]

[image]

The problem has definitely to do with the Adobe PDF engine, because Texmaker (the software I use to write Tex) shows the correct colors in the PDF-viewer.

Is there any way to fix this problem? Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16061/9632),, and also [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60316/9632). Perhaps you find help there.

Comment: @Sveinung Thank you very much, it works perfectly!