# Stop printing non-bold text in bold from PDF file

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf, bold, transparency

Despite everything, this problem is still occurring so I have re-opened the question. Even with:

`\pdfpageattr {/Group << /S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>}`

Appended to the preamble of the MWE, I still get bold text printing where it should not be.

Can anyone advise?

Everything posted below from the original question remain valid:

When I print pages of a PDF generated from a LaTeX document, non-bold text is sometimes printed in bold. There doesn't appear to be a pattern to this but the bold text does seem to be apparent around the pages which have graphics embedded in them.

My document is generated from PDFLaTeX using MikTex 2.9 via WinEdt 9.

I know that this issue has been raised in one form or another in other posts and I write with reference to [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60315/text-appearing-bold-on-some-pages-with-images/)

As there are rather a lot of PNG files in this document, can anyone tell me if this can be solved by simply removing transparency from my the PNG files? Or do I need to remove transparency from these graphics, or add the following line before every graphic:

```
\pdfpageattr {/Group << /S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>}
```

This is the sort of thing I mean where the bold which should not be bold is underlined.

Despite everything, this problem is still occurring so I have re-opened the question. Even with:

`\pdfpageattr {/Group << /S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>}`

Appended to the preamble of the MWE, I still get bold text printing where it should not be.

Can anyone advise?

[image: Scan of a page affected by this bold text which should not be bold]

A minimum worked example, with various customisations, follows approximately recreating the page shown above:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{changepage}
% \usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{footmisc}
% \usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}
% \usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage[acronym,footnote,nonumberlist]{glossaries} % Makes a list of abbreviations.
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{Text}

\usepackage[acronym,footnote,nonumberlist]{glossaries} 
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{Text}

\include{DummyAbbreviations}

\makeglossaries
\glossarystyle{mcolindex}

\makeatletter

\let\LaTeXStandardPart\part%
\newcommand{\unstarredpart@@noopt}[1]{%
    \unstarredpart@@opt[#1]{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\unstarredpart@@opt}[2][]{%
    \cleardoublepage% 
    \begingroup%
    \let\newpage\relax%
    \LaTeXStandardPart[#1]{#2}%
    \endgroup%
}

\newcommand{\starredpart}[1]{%
    \LaTeXStandardPart*{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\unstarredpart}{%
    \@ifnextchar[{\unstarredpart@@opt}{\unstarredpart@@noopt}%
}

\renewcommand{\part}{%
  \@ifstar{\starredpart}{\unstarredpart}%
}

\begin{document}

    \pagenumbering{roman}

    \begin{Huge}
    \noindent \textbf{Title}\\


    \noindent \textbf{Department}\\


    \noindent \textbf{College}\\


    \noindent \textbf{University}\\

    \end{Huge}               

    \tableofcontents

    \clearpage

    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \section{MWE}

    A typical visualisation includes two charts: 

    \begin{enumerate}
      \item An aggregation displaying the frequencies of keyword updates since polling began. The chart type is the one defined by the user for a sample visualisation (Section 1.4.1) prior to a new set of mining rules being persisted to the database.
      \item A time-series (Chapter ??, Section ??) plot depicts keyword frequency fluctuations during the period of the aggregation.
    \end{enumerate}

\begin{figure} [H]
    \centering{\includegraphics[scale=0.63]{Visualisation.png}}
    \caption{A typical visualisation displaying the aggregation of keyword frequencies (top) in a user-selected column chart, and a time-series plot of the fluctuations in the keyword frequencies (bottom).}
    \label{fig:Visualisation}
\end{figure}


    \bookmarksetupnext{level=-1}
    % Print figures.
    \clearpage% or \clearpage under the oneside option
    \phantomsection% Mark a hyperref link location
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}% Add contents entry for List of Tables
    \bibliography{DummyBibliography}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Give me a few minutes to create an MWE and I will post it.

Comment: Moreover, your link is broken. I edited your post to fix it but it seems you rejected my edit.

Comment: I think I inadvertently rejected the revision. the link is now repaired.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks Martin: I thought my question might be a duplicate but wanted to be sure. And I included the additional content to the MWE just in case it was something to do with the problem.