# Why has my output PDF file pages with heavy/thick font?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pdf, compiling

So I have had this problem for a while:
I have a document which includes many other .tex, .pdf, .png, .jpeg files. This document is around 200MB, but the problem occurs when only compiling parts of the document as well.

This is part of my documentclass:

```
\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=3.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\newcommand\bmmax{0} 
\widowpenalty = 10000        
\clubpenalty  = 10000        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

I have already switched to a T1 encoded font because I was dealing with fuzzy-looking. That problem doesn't exist any longer, now my PDF looks mostly fine using Adobe Acrobat Reader Pro. However, there are a couple pages where the text is entirely bold-looking. Even the bold fonts are bolder-looking. Interestingly, it always occurs on the same pages in one document, even when compiling only parts of it. I wasn't able to create a MWE though.

I thought it had something to do with the compression of the pdf, so I tried explicitly setting

```
\pdfcompresslevel=9
```

It actually got a little better, even when commenting that out again or setting it to a different number. But there is still a slight difference between these faulty pages and the normal ones and it's starting to really bug me.

Has anyone ever had the same problem or might have a few ideas on what else to try to improve the quality of the PDF file consistently?

Maybe these can illustrate my problem a little better:

[image: Bold-looking when it was worse]
[image: Normal text]

Left is heavy font, right is normal.

Comment: Are there graphics on the pages? See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141/why-are-some-pages-in-my-pdf-coming-out-bold

Comment: probably this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60316/1090

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I haven't found those posts yet and I am sorry. I just didn't see the link to the graphics since I don't review every one of them. It is now working so far.

Comment: I am experiencing this problem again. Changing pdfpageattr to fix rendering is making my whole document coming out bold lately. Could there be a connection to \pdfcompresslevel or any other pdf setting?

Comment: So far, the only thing fixing my problem was using the Preflight Tool in Adobe to reduce transparency. However, Adobe said the PDF did not contain any transparent objects.