# LaTeX Ouputs PDF with one page entirely bold

Tags: fonts, bold, acrobat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are some pages in my PDF coming out bold?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141/why-are-some-pages-in-my-pdf-coming-out-bold)

I have searched all over and cannot seem to find anyone else even mentioning this problem. I created a conference paper fully formatted using the conference's template in LaTeX (MikTeX/TeXworks on Windows). It looks just fine in the TeXWorks previewer, but when I open the document with Adobe Reader, the second and 7th pages (out of 8 total) are entirely in bold, including all of the text and captions. The figures appear unaffected.

I can't come up with any reason this would happen, but it was happening before when I used a different template, as well. The document source is relatively simple, and there aren't any commands in there to do anything like this. The document displayed this way on both computers I tested it on, and it prints just fine, too. Does anyone know what this happens when I try to view it in Adobe Reader? Is it just a bug with my version (10.1.2)?

Comment: Maybe something messed up with some \thispagestyle{empty} when you begin a chapter or something like that. Page style is always set to default on first page of a chapter, so maybe you will need to override the default page style instead of using another one.

Comment: @ChrisJamesC This would make sense, I think, but this isn't the first page of a chapter or any sort of special page, they are just 'normal' pages (I'm not using chapters here). At the start of the document the template had
`\thispagestyle{plain}`
`\pagestyle{plain}`
but those are the only instances of that command in this document. Does that make sense?

Comment: If I were you I would try to remove stuff in your header/instructions until the bug "disappears" and then search on it or tell in comments. (I am not an expert on this subject but this is how I usually do with latex)

Comment: Sorry, I was unaware of that site until now. Also, after just changing around some of my captions (text changes only, no formatting), this issue went away. I think it might just be a strange bug with Adobe Reader and how it is interpreting the file, and not actually related to LaTeX. Otherwise possibly LaTeX misplaces a character in the file in some rare instances. So my guess is that there isn't a solution to this, you just have to play around with it until it changes enough to disappear.

Comment: did you delete the .aux files? Sometimes it comes from there. I'm glad your problem is solved.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915484/latex-ouputs-pdf-with-one-page-entirely-bold?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141/why-are-some-pages-in-my-pdf-coming-out-bold. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly.

Comment: Thanks for moving this. @doncherry you're right, that solved my problem. Thanks a lot! All I had to do was remove any transparency from my images (I just put a white background in using photoshop), but I also had to convert some of them to jpegs rather than pngs, but it still worked. Thanks!

Comment: @tsteiner: You're welcome. I'll now vote to close this question.