# When printing document, why do pages with figures appear rougher (of lower resolution) than text-only pages?

Tags: pdf, printing, resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are some pages in my PDF coming out bold?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141/why-are-some-pages-in-my-pdf-coming-out-bold)

I have a PDF document that I made in LaTeX. Some pages contain figures I created in METAPOST. Everything is super-smooth in my PDF viewer, i.e. it's clearly nicely vectorized as it should be when I zoom way in.

However, upon printing the document (on a HP laser printer at the school), only the text-only pages appear smoothly in a good resolution as they should be. The pages with the figures get printed with a rougher lower resolution—even the text on those pages!

I tried two different laser printers at the school, one connected to Mac OS X and the other to Linux. Similar weird results for both.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

I suspect that pages containing the figures are being treated as images, and printed as images by the printer. But I have no idea whether this is the case, and if this is the case, I have no idea why this should be happening.

**UPDATE:** Could it have something to do with the fact that the figure contains a gray color (somewhere between white and black)? Does that cause the printer to go into some kind of a “color mode” for that page? Could that explain this?