# text gets slightly bold when adding graphics

Tags: fonts, graphics, pdf, bold

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are some pages in my PDF coming out bold?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141/why-are-some-pages-in-my-pdf-coming-out-bold)

I have problem with text on the page with a graph, it gets slightly thicker. The text on the next page without graph is normal.

Hopefully you are able to see the difference:

[image]

The culprit are these lines:

```
 \begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width=1.0\columnwidth]{times}
 \end{center}
```

The problem is well described in here too:
http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=7533

If you don't want to follow a link then essentially, a possible answer from there:

"This is usually caused by alpha channels in included graphics.

Remove the alpha channel in the included graphics (something I cannot help you with)"

Additional question within an answer - how?

Comment: You could use Imagemagick to remove the transparency, using `convert image.png  -background white -flatten +matte image_new.png` (taken from http://studio.imagemagick.org/pipermail/magick-users/2006-August/018215.html).

Comment: yes indeed, however here I found working solution ;-) Font returns back to normal in Adobe Reader.

Comment: Why don't you add your answer to the existing question instead of opening a new one?

Comment: I believe here the name better reflects the problem, additional tags can be added. Plus here thread is clean. I don't mind however at all if you insist.

Comment: @Jake I believe you should include your `convert` answer into the thread you linked and this thread can be closed then.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone troubling with this problem it is possible because of transparency effect you add to graphics which introduces alpha channel, which will break your font. GIMP (opensource) will help to process image.

1. Fire up [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/downloads/)
2. Open the image for which the alpha channel has to be removed
3. Click the Image menu on the image window
4. Click Flatten Image from the pull down menu
5. Save

taken from http://www.techchorus.net/how-do-i-remove-alpha-channel-image-using-gimp

Font should return back, remember to do it for every graphics file you use.

I also tried to do it in Photoshop CS5, however under 'channels' it didn't list alpha channel, so be aware it might not work in there.