# MathTime Professional II Lite Font Weight

Tags: fonts, mtpro

I have a doubt about the font "MathTime Professional II Lite". I've installed it, however the math seems to be bold. I'm not sure why this is happening, but I'm trying to find a way to make it lighter. Anyone knows how to deal with this issue?

Comment: Could you post an MWE (minimum working example) that would allow us to see what you have in mind? The claim "the math seems to be bold" is difficult to evaluate without something to work with/look at. Do you have an alternative font with Times Roman glyph shapes that you prefer?

Comment: Hi @Mico, sorry for that, I'll put an example right now. For an example there's the font used in "A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry" from Spivak. Should I post a image of that font too ? Thanks very much

Comment: Note that the "Lite" in the name refers to lack of full features, compared to the professional version, not the font weight.  mafp's answer below gives a good illustration of what fits together well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MathTime Pro was developed as a companion for Times(-like) fonts. So it look indeed too bold when used with the standard Latin Modern font (first column). It fits much better with `LinuxLibertine` (second column), or `newtx` (third column).

[image: font comparison]

Answer (score 0):

By any chance is there a figure nearby?  If so, the problem could be related to the alpha channel of the picture.

Now, if this is the case, there are two main solutions to remove the alpha channel:

1. Using GIMP, as described in [text gets slightly bold when adding graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49199/text-gets-slightly-bold-when-adding-graphics/49200#49200).
2. Using ImageMagik, as described in [Why are some pages in my PDF coming out bold?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141/why-are-some-pages-in-my-pdf-coming-out-bold/172#172).

Comment: Hi Mario, there aren't any figures. Do you know a way to deal with this kind of thing when there aren't figures? By the way, is there a way to control the font weight in general ?

Comment: You can take a look at [this post]http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27843/level-of-boldness-changeable/27875#27875 and [this one]http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25184/set-the-font-weight-lighter-bolder

Comment: Some friendly thoughts: Instead of linking Mario to [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/27833/mario-s-e) and [there](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107008/15717), `this` and `that`. How about linking like [Answer to "text gets slightly bold when adding graphics" by Aubergine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49200/27833). BTW press the help button in comment box to properly get the hyperlink. `[Title of Question](Link)` . I know sometimes characters are limited in comment atleast when we have, use it.

Comment: @texenthusiast Thanks, I was hoping someone could help me with the hyperlinks :)

Comment: @MarioS.E. When in doubt: Always post a Q at [meta.tex.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/), Remember to search first incase if it has an answer at meta.

Comment: @texenthusiast (\OT) That's the reason why when you search for [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=here) the Adobe Reader is one of the top results, because “you can download Adobe Reader [here](http://localhost).” (\endOT) @OP Links to questions get automatically translated into `[Title of the question](link)`.