# including a figure interferes with text font

Tags: fonts, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are some pages in my PDF coming out bold?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141/why-are-some-pages-in-my-pdf-coming-out-bold)

I'm having a bit weird of an issue with including graphics into my LaTeX documents. 
When including a pdf graphics into a LaTeX document, the text font gets corrupted on the page of the final pdf document where the figure is placed  --- for some figures.

Here is the minimal example: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18720218/fonts.tgz
(apologies for the external link). In my environment, the font on pages one and three is OK, but on page two it's somehow blurry (or just different). Sure, it's not a show-stopper, the text is still readable, but it's somewhat unpleasant, so to say.

So I'm wondering if this is just a problem of my environment (can anybody reproduce the problem?), and if not, then what can possibly be the cause and how to overcome it.

Both pdf graphics files were generated by `matplotlib` if that matters--- but for TeX, it's just a pdf, right?

I'm using `pdflatex` from `TeXLive2009` on `Ubuntu Lucid` if that matters. 
Any hints or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possibly same issue as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141/why-are-some-pages-in-my-pdf-coming-out-bold

Comment: Ah. Indeed, in `xpdf` or `evince` instead of acrobat all the pages look the same (awful). So, the issue is most probably with the acrobat viewer, hence is a non-issue. If you put your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Otherwise, please feel free to close the question.