# Including graphics modifies the font of the page on which they are inserted

Tags: fonts, graphics

I have some issue with the fonts in my document. When I insert some of my pdf figure, the font of the page where they are inserted is modified. I use pdflatex to compile and all my figures are in pdf format.

Do you have any idea how to avoid that my inserted pictures compromise the font of the page ?

Comment: Related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141/why-are-some-pages-in-my-pdf-coming-out-bold

Comment: Thank you a lot it was indeed a problem of rendering in adobe reader as stated in the post mentioned by lockstep.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.